# How to find WPF TextBox's changed text?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, custom-controls, textchanged

Suppose we inherit from WPF `TextBox` and then try to get text changes through overriding `OnTextChanged`.

Then we would notice when changes occurred, but the only information that we would have is:

- Offset that this change occurred
- Removed Length
- Added Length

Can we get the accurate added text by using,

```
Text.Substring(Change.Offset, Change.AddedLength)
```

in `OnTextChanged`?

Text Change occurs in different conditions (such as user input, pasting text, or setting `Text` property in-code). Is there any possibility of conflicting changes coming into `e.Changes`?

Is this approach a trust way? If answer is No, Is there any other standard way(s) to get accurate changed text?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50067245/9285072

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a TextBox, this event occurs when its text changes; for a RichTextBox, this event occurs when any content or formatting changes (for example, images, table, or background color).

1. Can we get the accurate added text by using ... ?

Yes, you will always get accurate text in case of TextBox. You can make use of e.UndoAction to check for addition/deletion of text.
Read [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.undoaction(v=vs.110).aspx) here.

2. Is there any possibility of conflicting changes coming into e.Changes?

There won't be conflicting changes.

In general, the following will always be true:

> - The changes that occur result in the document being in a valid state.
>        The collection is ordered consecutively, related to where the change    occurred in the control. For example, a TextChange object
>     that    represents a change at position 2 is before a TextChange
>     object that    represents a change at position 10.
> - Two TextChange objects do not represent an overlapping area. The       value of Offset plus the value of AddedLength of one TextChange
>     object is always less than or equal to the value of Offset of the
>     next TextChange object in the collection. Likewise, the value of
>     Offset plus the value of RemovedLength of one TextChange object is
>     always less than or equal to the value of Offset of the next
>     TextChange object in the collection.
> - The collection reflects whatever changes occurred, even if there       seems to be no net change. In the preceding example, neither the
>     first or fourth change results in a net change, because each simply
>     removed and re-added the  and  symbols, respectively. But
>     the symbols were actually removed and added, so they are included in
>     the collection.

More can be read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textchangedeventargs.changes(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I made a short test program with one TextBox and one Label and I could not find the problems you describe. If I implement an TextChanged event for the TextBox like the following it works even if I paste something.The checking for null is needed because if the Textbox has an initial value the Initilialize method will trigger the change event before the label is created.

```
 private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tbSource = (sender as TextBox);

        if (lblOutput == null)
            return; 

        lblOutput.Content = tbSource.Text; 

    }
```